# server.servlet.contextPath vs spring.mvc.servlet.path

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Consider the below code,

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1")
class Controller {

}
```

What I am supposed to do is, **remove the @RequestMapping** and configure the path through **application.properties**.

I came across two ways with which I can achieve this,

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/v1
```

and

```
server.servlet.contextPath=/v1
```

But how do they differ, since I haven't noticed any difference in both these configurations? Which one would be ideal for what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The context path is a name with which a web application is accessed. It is the root of the application and by default, Spring Boot serves the content on the root context path (“/”). This context path can be changed with the property `server.servlet.context-path`.

On the other hand, the servlet path represents the path of the main `DispatcherServlet`. The default value is similar to the context path, i.e. (“/”) and it can be changed by configuring a different `spring.mvc.servlet.path` property. Given that a servlet belongs to a servlet context, changing the context path will also affect the servlet path.

Keeping both pieces of information in mind if you have the following configuration:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/context-path
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/servlet-path
```

Then the application servlet path will become `http://localhost:8080/context-path/servlet-path`.

Having written all this, I would say that in your case it is ok to use any of the properties.

Answer (score 4):

Spring Boot offers both ("/") by default.

If we enter different values for both, their difference will appear;

For example:

```
spring.mvc.servlet.path=/test
server.servlet.contextPath=/demo
```

this endpoints: `http://localhost:8080/demo/test/.....`

Answer (score 1):

By `server.servlet.contextPath` means the path by which your application will be accessed by the end users where `spring.mvc.servlet.path` means the servlet path. *If you don't set any servlet path[default value is `/`]*, `contextPath` will be used for user's interaction with your service. But if `servlet` path is provided, then you context path will be changed like this:

```
http://application_domain_name:port/cotextPath_provided/_servlet_path_provided
```